# Multiple-value sorting comparator for sorting Gtk treeView

Tags: python, sorting, comparator, gtk3

I followed the [python Gtk2 tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html). There is a possibility to sort the treeView or listView elements acording to custom separator function:

```
def compare(model, row1, row2, user_data):
    sort_column = 0
    value1 = model.get_value(row1, sort_column)
    value2 = model.get_value(row2, sort_column)
    # here beginns the interresting part
    if value1 < value2:
        return -1
    elif value1 == value2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

In my treeStore model I stored filenames and is_directory bool values. The sorting should be: first directories alphabeticaly and then files alphabeticaly.

I need to adapt the comparator, co it can work on two values: filenames and the bool values if those are directories or not.

I tried:

```
def compareFileListEntries(self, fileListModel, row1, row2, user_data):

        name1 = fileListModel.get_value(row1, 1)
        name2 = fileListModel.get_value(row2, 1)
        isDir1 = fileListModel.get_value(row1, 2)
        isDir2 = fileListModel.get_value(row2, 2)

        if isDir1 < isDir2:
            return -1
        elif isDir1 > isDir2:
            return 1
        else:
            if name1 < name2:
                return -1
            elif name1 == name2:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
```

This sorts the directories first - in random order and then the files also randomly. Could please someone point me to my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue were in another part. The above code is basically all right. I made some adaptations, so the the sorting works as follows: directories first, alphabetically, case-insensitive. The names are stored in the first column of my treeStore model, the isDirectory values in the second. Here is the code I ended with:

```
def compareFileListEntries(self, fileListModel, row1, row2, user_data):

        name1 = fileListModel.get_value(row1, 0).lower()
        name2 = fileListModel.get_value(row2, 0).lower()
        isDir1 = fileListModel.get_value(row1, 1)
        isDir2 = fileListModel.get_value(row2, 1)

        if isDir1 > isDir2:
            return -1
        elif isDir1 < isDir2:
            return 1
        else:
            if name1 < name2:
                return -1
            elif name1 == name2:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
```